# Neo4j DateTime ValidationError

Tags: node.js, validation, datetime, neo4j, joi

I'm trying to update a field with `datetime` datatype for Neo4j instance running locally. 
I'm using [neode](https://github.com/adam-cowley/neode) with NodeJs `v12.5.0` and Neo4j `Version: 3.5.7` community edition running via docker.

My model snippet:

```
module.exports = {
...
"fieldName": "datetime"
...
}
```

My code snippet:

```
...
user.update({
    id: 'someid',
    fieldName: new Date()
})
...
```

But joi seems to be throwing this error:
`Error [ValidationError]: child "fieldName" fails because ["fieldName" must be an instance of "DateTime"]`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the driver try this.

```
const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver')
const getDateTime = d => {
  return neo4j.default.types.DateTime.fromStandardDate(d); // Example: d = new Date();
}
```

And use getDateTime function to get Datetime format.

Answer (score 0):

maybe because it should be new Date(). Because it's not actually creating a new instance by calling the constructor and is instead a reference to the constructor.

Comment: Don't think so. Have tried with `new Date()` as well as [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/). Doesn't work either way.